# Join specific string indexes python

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python, I am making a print program which reads from a file (entered when running from the command line) the following line: `line 'hello world'`.
However, when I split this string by spaces with `file.readline().split(" ")`, it returns the array `["line", "'hello", "world'\n"]` as expected. Is there a way I can turn the two indexes `"'hello"` and `"world'\n"` into one index, `"'hello world'\n"` without creating a new array without `'line'`?

Comment: regex is your friend

Comment: What's regex? I've never heard of it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `file.readline().split(" ")[1:]`

this will create one array that has all the items in the array given by `file.readline().split(" ")` other then the first item

then you can loop in a for loop on that array and join everything to a string with

```
for i in file.readline().split(" ")[1:]:
    str += (file.readline().split(" ")[1:])[i] + " "
```

Comment: I actually want to be able to use any file containing anything that says `line x` and have it print x. Also, that doesn't do anything different. I also asked "without creating a new array without 'line'".

Comment: he wants to join "hello" "world" too.

Comment: it returns an array that has the 2nd and 3rd items from the original array. that is what you asked for in your question if i understand correctly, i don't quite understand what you are asking for from this comment

Comment: I asked to combine them into 1 index. This returns the same array as before.

Comment: if you want all of the items in an array other then the first one use [1:] if you then want to add all of the items one after the other to a string you MUST creat a new variable, i don't think there is any other way that is not 10 times more complex. just loop in a for loop over the array from 1 to the end and not from 0 to the end and add them all to a string

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help

Comment: are you sure that adding [1:3] returns the same string i just checked on a random list i created and I definitely works as it said

Comment: It returns the string ["'hello", "world'\n"]. Like I said in the question, I wanted to get the result ["'hello world'\n".]

Comment: you still want it to be an array with only one item? why would you want that? if you do just use the string that you got as a single item in an array